# Are there non-magical people born into magical families?

Tags: harry-potter, magic, muggles

Is there any case in the Harry Potter-verse of someone *magic born* but having no magic skills? I haven't read enough to know why muggleborns can have magic powers but if it works one way then maybe the other?

Comment: These are called [squibs](https://www.pottermore.com/features/everything-you-need-to-know-about-squibs) and form quite a prominent part of the series.(Note: the link isn't to a strictly canonical source)

Comment: @Edlothiad can you explain what you mean by 'isn't canonical source' please?

Comment: It's not canon, it's written by a group of people that aren't JKR, although are under her payroll. It's not to be taken as gospel and likely takes it's information from sources which are canonical. However if one were to quote, they should find the primary source, this is merely a secondary source.

Comment: @Edlothiad so the answer below isn't correct? My books are in a box somewhere so don't have them to hand

Comment: I'm just talking about the link I posted. The information is likely accurate in the link, but not necessarily from a primary source. The answer below is certainly quoting accurately from reputable sources.

Comment: @Edlothiad thank, I put a lot of trust in your answers so wanted to check before pulling the garage apart for my copies!

Comment: The answer below isn't mine. It's someone else's.

Comment: That's why I asked if it was correct.

Comment: @Seamusthedog The answer's quotes are taken directly from the books... It's rather correct I'd say :p

Comment: Ah yes, it probably is. I'm not an expert in everything. Except maybe in how this site runs, and what are and are not canonical in main works.

Comment: I'm upset I didn't think about that first...

Comment: I like the way you have Aragon about this....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, such people are called "Squibs". We first see this in *Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*, when we are told that Argus Filch - the caretaker of the school - is a Squib.

> "And what on earth’s a Squib?" said Harry.
>   To his surprise, Ron stifled a snigger.
>   "Well – it’s not funny really – but as it’s Filch ..." he said. "A Squib is someone who was born into a wizarding family but hasn’t got any magic powers. Kind of the opposite of Muggle-born wizards, but Squibs are quite unusual. If Filch’s trying to learn magic from a Kwikspell course, I reckon he must be a Squib. It would explain a lot. Like why he hates students so much." Ron gave a satisfied smile. "He’s bitter."
>   <sub>*Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*, chapter 9: "The Writing on the Wall"</sub>

Other examples include Arabella Figg (as we see in *The Order of the Pheonix*), and Neville Longbottom was thought to be a Squib at first.

> "Arabella Doreen Figg," said Mrs. Figg in her quavery voice.
>   "And who exactly are you?" said Fudge, in a bored and lofty voice.
>   "I’m a resident of Little Whinging, close to where Harry Potter lives," said Mrs. Figg.
>   "We have no record of any witch or wizard living in Little Whinging, other than Harry Potter," said Madam Bones at once. "That situation has always been closely monitored, given ... given past events."
>   "I’m a Squib," said Mrs. Figg. ‘So you wouldn’t have me registered, would you?"
>   "A Squib, eh?" said Fudge, eyeing her suspiciously. "We’ll be checking that. You’ll leave details of your parentage with my assistant Weasley. Incidentally, can Squibs see Dementors?" he added, looking left and right along the bench.
>   <sub>*Harry Potter and the Order of Pheonix*, courtesy of [Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/book-extract-long/mrs-figg-witness)</sub>